# Are there any 64-bit Executable Packers?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, software-rec, packer

Is there a good, free packer out there for 64-bit executables?

I'm looking for something like UPX, except that UPX doesn't seem to support 64-bit executables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no personal experience with this, but here is one.

http://www.matcode.com/mpress.htm

Not Free
http://www.larp64.com/

Comment: +1 mpress is exactly what I was looking for, with one caveat: it doesn't support TLS callbacks.